# How to run a function (passing vectors that stay the same & vector that changes in each iteration) without using a for loop?

Tags: r, for-loop, lapply

I need to run a function a fixed number of times.

In each step:

- 'vol' and 'ad' remain the same.
- 'adnew' is  calculated by replacing element of 'vol' (whose f = 1) with 'step'

Final output: 'vol_new' - matrix or list with 11 number of elements, each element consists of a vector of length 5.

Thank you for your help!

**EXAMPLE CODE**

```
vol     <- c(15, 10, 25, 40, 45)
ad      <- c(100, 200, 300, 150, 250)

# filter - stays the same
f     <- c( 1, 1, 1, 0, 0)

# need to loop it 10 times (looping through 'step')

step =  seq(0, 500, by = 50)

# for each 'step', adnew is calculated by replacing element of vol (whose f = 1) with 'step'
adnew <- rep(list(ad), length(step))

for (i in 1:length(step)) {
  adnew[[i]][f==1] <- step[i]
}      

# for each step, calculate the function 'calc'
Calc <- function(vol, ad, adnew) {
  return((adnew/ad)*vol)
}

# desired output:

vol_new -- a matrix or list with 11 elements (corresponds to number of iterations), each element consisting of a vector of size 5.
```

Comment: Calc will return a vector for each step. I'm not sure I understand how the output from that goes into `vol_new`. Could you explain the logic of this in words? This is probably a lot more convoluted than it has to be

Comment: You are correct. Volnew will be a matrix or list with size 11 (number of iterations), each with a vector of size 5. Really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

It turns out to be an application of lappy.

```
vol_new = lapply(adnew, function(x) {return((x/ad)*vol)})
```